# Jquery: getting values from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, variables

I was wondering how to get values from mysql?

In php i would use something like

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $value = $row['name'];
}
```

But how do I get something from $value in jquery? Say I want to use a value from $value and put in a

```
var Value = $value;
```

or something like that?

Thank you

Comment: do you want to make php communicate with your javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Value = <?php echo json_encode($value) ?>;
```

Assuming `$value` contains a string, it will be encoded as `".."` after escaping any double quote characters present in the string itself.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to combine server-side scripting with client-side scripting here. I suggest you output data from your PHP code like this:

```
<div id="myDiv"><?php echo $value; ?></div>
```

and then write your jQuery code to pick it from there:

```
var Value = $('#myDiv').text();
```

Comment: And just like this you cluttering up your DOM model.

Comment: From what I understood, he never mentioned it was supposed to be done with inline JavaScript. I'm sure he can take it from here :)

Comment: What does this mean by cluttering up my DOM and inline javascript?

Comment: @andrewliu It means there's a `<div` node in your document whose only purpose is passing the value, which is kinda dirty. And the answer by @Anurang just outputs the string inside your `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
var Value = "<?php echo $value ?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var value = <?php echo "'$value'"; ?>
</script>
```